# Strange behaviour of Apache with network drive

Tags: apache-2.2, network-share, mongrel

Hii all, Am runnnig Apache web server in front of mongrel server and mapped a network drive on my system.In my application miongrel is doing file upload to network drive and apche is serving file from network .

But i disconnected the network drive and what strange behaviour am getting still am able to uplaod as well as download files to and from network drive .could anyone tell me why is it so. Am on windows NT machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using the UNC and not the mapped drive letter. You can write to a UNC as long as you have permission, even if it's not explicitly mapped.

Comment: one thing i would really like to know ,i mapped a network drive under local system acount ,i mean i log on into my machine local sytem account .then i loged  off the machine and loginto my machine using some other valid user account ...here i could n't see the drive that i mapped under local system but i can use that drive in application... is it usual??

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't be able to log in interactively with SYSTEM...